# Exploding JSON with foreach using PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach, explode

I tried to explode some JSON but I got an error, `"Undefined offset: 1."` I don't know how to fix it. I tried to `var_dump` the JSON content, it shows the string word I need. However, when I try to `explode` and `foreach` it, I get an error. Please help me.

**This is the code:**

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/project/services/grafik');
$encoding = json_encode($json,true);
$pecah = explode(",",$encoding);
// var_dump($pecah);

foreach($pecah as $row => $data)
{
    $p1 = explode(',', $data);
    $p2[$row] = explode(',',$p1[0]);
    $nama=$p2[$row][0];
    $jumlah=$p2[$row][1];
}
```

**This is the JSON content:**

```
"Windows XP Prof ,106, Windows 7 ,43, Windows Vista Business ,13, Windows 7 Prof ,21, B4 ,1, Windws 7 Prof ,1, IPCOP ,1, Windows 2003 server ,4, Windows 2008 server ,1, Windows 2008 R2 ,4, NULL ,9, Windows 8 Prof ,6,operating,1,"
```

Comment: What you are looking for is `json_decode()`.

Comment: i have used decode, but when i used decode, it become very complicated, i received NULL when i tested JSON with var_dump. first time i create this the data still appear on $nama and $jumlah, then there's error offset. but now.. i do not know what im doing, its become more difficult $nama and $jumlah does not appear anymore..just error offset appear.

Comment: `$pecah = json_decode($encoding, true);` this way the json will be decoded into an array which will make it less complicated.

Comment: many thanks any people for feedback, i tried decode the $encoding, but its return NULL value..,

Comment: What's the value of `$json`? Do a `var_dump($json)`.

Comment: try to decode $json not  $encoding because `json_decode()` has second optional parameter which you can set to true end json_encode second parameter a bitmask

Comment: update : i have decoded then works on decoded now, but it also error  '$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/project/services/grafik');
    $encoding = json_encode($json,true);
  $pecah = json_decode($encoding,true); foreach($pecah as $row )
    {
   $p1 = explode(',', $row);
   //echo $p1[0];
   var_dump ($p1);